# Google Drive conditional formatting with multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, drive

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet on Google Drive were I can monitor whether all information is filled.
If Cell A1 is filled with anyhting, I want cell A2 to be filled with a color... this is easy.
Additionally I want Cell A2 to lose it's color again, when someone has put information in cell A2.
Can anyone explain if this is possible and if, how?

Comment: explain in more detail relation between google drive and google sheets & what are you after exactly

Comment: Thank you Carlos, I didn't know the first rule and the second rule would have to be in this order. This works perfectly :)

Comment: If I answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I do not have an accept button, where should it be visable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

You can use conditional formatting `Format menu -> Conditional Formatting` in Google Sheets like this:

[image]

**First rule:**

[image]

**Second rule:**

[image]